# How to move bodies connected with constraint in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have an object that consists of multiple bodies connected with constraints. This is not a `compound` body in terms of `matter.js` because, in my case, bodies can rotate independently.

The problem is that when I'm trying to move one of the `bodies` using `setPosition` (see demo below), I'm expecting the other linked bodies to move too based on the constraint, but it is not the case. Instead, the matter.js solver makes them rotate arbitrarily as I have applied some force to them. To work around this, I can potentially remove constraints, move bodies, and then re-apply the constraint but it feels too complicated (imagine that I have many bodies and constraints between them) and not elegant.

Question: Is there a way in `matter.js` to move multiple `bodies` connected with constraints?

The problem demo:

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
engine.world.gravity.y = 0;

const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.querySelector('#container'),
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    showAngleIndicator: false
  }
});

const bodyA = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(50, 50, 20, 60);
const bodyB = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(80, 30, 60, 20);
const constraintAB = Matter.Constraint.create({
  bodyA,
  bodyB,
  pointA: {
    x: 10,
    y: -20
  },
  pointB: {
    x: -30,
    y: 0
  },
  length: 0,
  stiffness: 0.9,
});

Matter.World.add(engine.world, constraintAB);
Matter.World.add(engine.world, [bodyA, bodyB]);

const runner = Matter.Runner.create();
Matter.Runner.run(runner, engine);
Matter.Render.run(render);

setTimeout(() => {
  Matter.Body.setPosition(bodyA, { x: 400, y: 200 });
  
  // Moving on small distance works but this is not what I need
  // Matter.Body.translate(bodyA, { x: 2, y: 2 });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-0z8URjGET6GWnS1xcgiLBZBzoaS8BNlKayfZyQNKz4IRp+s7CKXx0yz7Eco2+TcwoeMBa5KMwmTX7Kus7Fa5Uw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='container' style='width: 500px; height: 500px'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no matter-specific way to move multiple bodies, if they are not all parts of a compound body. But in your case, it is enough to translate all bodies connected with constraint, instead of just one. You also should set unique label for each such group of bodies. You won't have to reapply constaints using this approach.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const allBodies = Composite.allBodies(engine.world).filter(
    (el) => el.label === "my-label"
  );

  allBodies.forEach((el) => {
    Body.translate(el, { x: 200, y: 100 });
  });
}, 2000);
```